# VSCode keeps complaining there is no "process.env"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a file `test/test.ts` which is as simple as one line:

```
process.env["NODE_ENV"] = 'test';
```

My VSCode complains that it cannot find 'process':

> Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.ts(2580)

However, when I run the Typescript compiler `tsc test/test.ts` is happy with the file without any error.

Of cource I have installed `@types/node`, but VSCode is still complaining. How can I fix that?